# Ошибка при деплое проекта на Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Заливаю сгенерированный проект на Vue3 на сервер. Проект лежит в отдельной папке. При обращении к сайту, возникает ошибка по типу

```
https://domen/assets/index-chank.js - Not Found 404, 
не может найти файл, так как он лежит по по адресу https://domen/sayt/assets/index-chank.js.
```

Судя по ошибке, нужно поменять настройки в vite.config.js, но на какие - в документации не нашёл.

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
build: {
        //cssCodeSplit: false, --- если нужно
        //jsCodeSplit: false,  --- если нужно
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                dir: './public/site_files', //---- определяем КУДА нужно
                assetFileNames: 'site.css',
                entryFileNames: 'site.js',
            },
        },
        emptyDir: true,
    },
```